# How to implement XOR without using ^?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, bit-manipulation

Is there a way to implement bitwise XOR without using `^` ?

1) with other bitwise operations?

2) with arithmetic operations?

Comment: Think about what `XOR` means - it should be obvious that a combination of OR, AND and NOT operations will do the trick.

Comment: What's wrong with `^`? There's an operator that does exactly what you want. Use it!

Comment: @MarcGlisse please answer. You deserve `V`

Comment: This seems like a logical problem rather than a programming one.

Comment: -1 for doing no research.

Comment: @RaymondChen One reason to not use it is when reverse engineering encryption people usually start by searching for an XOR operator in asm. If you don't use the XOR operator it obfuscates the location of the encryption routine slowing the attacker down.

Comment: @rollsch That's a very niche scenario, and if you're writing advanced encryption algorithms that are resistant to these sorts of attacks, finding an XOR equivalent is not much of a challenge. Under normal conditions (and there's no suggestion that we are outside of normal conditions), just use the XOR operator. That's why it's there.

Comment: It is niche, but its literally the reason I was searching for this SO question. We are programming for micros with limited CPU cycles inside of a loop that is accessed hundreds of thousands of times a second, so a simple XOR obfuscation is all we need (as its fast) and hiding the XOR instruction itself makes it difficult to see at a first glance what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to do that, but:
`(a|b)&~(a&b)` or `(a&~b)|(b&~a)`
An arithmetic version seems too complicated to try without a good reason.

Comment: One reason to not use it is when reverse engineering encryption people usually start by searching for an XOR operator in asm. If you don't use the XOR operator it obfuscates the location of the encryption routine slowing the attacker down.

Answer (score 12):

```
a xor b == (a and (not b)) or ((not a) and b)
```

Comment: Don't you want `bitand` etc for the bitwise versions?

Comment: I thought using words instead of symbols would make the answer clearer; those are bit operations.

Comment: Ok. Note that the standard does provide words with the right meaning: `bitand` for `&`, `bitor` for `|` and `compl` for `~`, whereas `and`, `or` and `not` are for logical operations (`&&`, `||` and `!`), which makes your answer a bit confusing.